Decomposing an endomorphism as a tensor product
$\DeclareMathOperator\End{End}$Let $f$ be an endomorphism of the finite-dimensional vector space $V$, over the field $K$. The question of whether $f$ is decomposable, that is, whether $V$ can be written as the direct sum $U\oplus W$ of two nontrivial subspaces which are stable under $f$, is perfectly understood. (If you can compute and factor the characteristic polynomial over $K$, you're done.) (Edit: the previous sentence is a little overstatement; but computing the Smith normal form of the matrix $f - X\cdot I$, with coefficients in $K[X]$, gives a full answer.)
I have recently realized that I know absolutely nothing of the analogous question when one replaces $\oplus$ by $\otimes$. That is, given $f$, can we decide whether we can find two vector spaces $U$ and $W$ both of dim $>1$, and an isomorphism $\phi : U\otimes W \to V$, such that $\phi^{-1}\circ f \circ \phi$ is of the form $\alpha\otimes \beta$ for $\alpha\in \End(U)$ and $\beta\in \End(W)$ ?
Much as in the case of $\oplus$, one can ask for abstract reasons why the decomposition should exist or not, but also for a practical way of constructing $U$, $W$, $\phi$.
One can give many necessary conditions (starting with the observation that $\dim V$ had better not be a prime number), but I don't know if there is a complete "theory" available.

One way to approach this problem is to use the theory of canonical forms. If you find the canonical form of the tensor product of two matrices in canonical form, this can be used as the beginning of an algorithm. For example, over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, the tensor product of $J_n(\lambda)$ with $J_m(\mu)$ with $n\geqslant m$ is $J_{n+m-1}(\lambda\mu)\oplus J_{n+m-3}(\lambda\mu) \oplus \cdots \oplus J_{n-m+1}(\lambda\mu)$. Tensor products of Jordan blocks in characteristic $p$ are understood, but harder to write down.

I added the representation theory tag, since one can rephrase this question as how to write a given $K[\mathbb{N}]$-representation as a (tensor) product of smaller representations.

@DaveBenson (sorry for the delay in replying) The algorithm you suggest boils down to "first, write down all the possible isomorphism classes of $K[X]$-modules of the form $U\otimes W$" (and it's true that it's manageable over an algebraically closed field) and "second, check whether $V$ is isomorphic to one of them" (and it's true that there are algorithms for that). However, it's not clear how to do this over $\mathbb{Q}$, and even over a large finite field the time necessary to carry out the computation might be a serious issue.
